# Is it OK to pass a null window handle to ShellExecute?

Tags: delphi, console, delphi-2010, shellexecute

I have a Delphi console application that at the end needs to launch one of two applications.

I'm having some problems getting ShellExecute to work without erroring, and I think the problem is associated with not having a handle for the console applicaiton.

The line that is causing me grief is:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'someapplication.exe', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

I think that the 0 in the handle is the problem as it compiles OK and runs in the debugger OK, but if I try to run the executable I get an unhandled error (the console application thinks that it has finished happily).

Comment: I think you need to disable "Debug Spawned Processes" in IDE, press F6 and type "debug spawned processes", if that's checked, uncheck it and try again

Comment: HWND(0) is HWND_DESKTOP, for your information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Passing 0 for the `hwnd` parameter is fine. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) describes the parameter thus:

> A handle to the parent window used for displaying a UI or error messages. This value can be NULL if the operation is not associated with a window.

Your error is due to something else.

Comment: Thanks - turns out I wasn't releasing my Data Module manually!